# Could not find acceptable ICU library

Tags: linux, delphi, firebird

I have a HORSE API that I use on a Linux Ubuntu 20.04 server. In this API, I use a Firebird 3.0 database.

Today, I made some small updates to some features, basically changing only some types of data entry. When I deployed the update, running the tests, this error started popping up:

[image]

If anyone has experienced this problem, can you help me, or give me some indication to work on some points to solve this problem?

Comment: You are running your code inside the debugger. Do you see the error if you run your code outside of the debugger, or tell the debugger to ignore EIBNativeException? Maybe the DB component you are using will handle the exception internally before it reaches your code

Comment: An ICU library is one of these ic*.dll files that come with FireBird

Comment: @JanDoggen The OP is using Linux, not Windows, and on Linux generally the system provided ICU library is used. As an aside, it is Firebird, not FireBird.

Comment: The error you have is unlikely to come from changes to your application, but from changes to your Linux installation or Firebird installation. I'd suggest trying to reinstall Firebird 3.0 on your server, preferably using a version provided by the package manager of your Linux.

Comment: The error happens regardless of how it is executed. I'm using firebird from the linux package manager, I've tried reinstalling it but it didn't work, I even tried other versions.

Comment: What is version of ICU library installed and what exact name of the function inside (according to 'nm icuuc* | grep u_setDataDirectory')? ICU is a crazy library with unpredictable naming.

Comment: libicu66 @user13964273

Comment: And the name of the function is...

Comment: BTW, is it possible that this time you have built 32 bits version of your application instead of 64 bits (or vice versa) so there is no ICU library of corresponding bitness on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and to solve it I put the path to `libfbclient.so` in `firebird.conf`.

```
UdfAccess = Restrict /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/firebird/3.0
```

[image: Screenshot]